# odoo/openERP: How to access mobile no. of attendee of meeting

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am writing a server action which will send an sms to the attendees of the meeting (status done) in odoo.

here is the code.

[image]

Actually there is no field of "mobile" on event. how can i access mobile no of all the attendees from here. It is actually easy in salesforce to do so, but i have no idea how it works in odoo.

Comment: We need more details about what is going on. Can you include the `send_sms` method in your question as well as what `records` is?

Comment: hey thanks for replying. i have installed an sms module and that module is working properly. i have tested it by sending message on quotation creation using automated actions. the thing is i dont know how can i access the fields of other modules from here.
here is the code for quotation creation. "env['sms.config'].send_sms(records.partner_id.mobile, 'your quotation has been created')".
i just need to send message to all persons who are attendees of the meeting.

Comment: hey  travisw, i found the solution. thanks a lot.

Comment: You should post your solution as am Answer in case anyone runs into a similar problem in the future.