# Is it possible to send SMS through automated action in Odoo V13 and above?

Tags: python, automation, sms, odoo-13

I am using Odoo Enterprise V13. I am trying to create an automated action to send SMS to the Sales Manager with specific mobile phone number as soon as a lead is created. I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839042/odoo-openerp-how-to-access-mobile-no-of-attendee-of-meeting) and tried this as python code in server action to simulate.

```
env['sms.composer'].action_send_sms({'numbers':'1386xxxxxxx', 'body':'New lead has been created in Odoo'})
```

- But it's giving an error `action_send_sms() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.
- What is the right syntax or is there another way to send SMS but
  through automated action and python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it. But first, create the `sms.composer` object and then send it.
Currently, you are calling a function that takes no arguments.

```py
my_sms = env['sms.composer'].create({'numbers':'1386xxxxxxx', 'body':'New lead has been created in Odoo'})
my_sms.action_send_sms()
```

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/65e5b31f346030b6efcecf0de0ae448aeff7aae2/addons/sms/wizard/sms_composer.py#L148

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. It solved my problem and am sure would help so many others.